# If statement inside a ForEach using csv

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, foreach

We are using powershell to create our student users automatically in our Active Directory.  We have everything working except the enable-mailbox.  We only give email addresses to our secondary students.  So I am trying to have the script read the csv and only enable-mailbox for secondary students.  All our secondary schools have campus numbers less than 100, so I tried to have the script use ForEach and then If $_.extensionAttribute1 (column in the csv with the campus number) is less then 100, then it will mail-enable the account.  The problem I am having is that only processes the first user and ends the script.  I am wanting it to run through each row in the csv.  Here is my script.

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

Import-CSV C:\scripts\updateuser.csv | ForEach {
    $campus =$_.extensionAttribute1
    If ($campus -lt '100') {
    Enable-Mailbox -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -Database NISDSRV6DB1
    }}
```

Any help you can provide to make this run through the entire csv would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT...I was messing around with the csv file and I got some interesting results.  The only way this script would display anything was if the extensionAttribute1 field was populated with a 1.  I am trying to get all users that are less than 100.

Comment: Your syntax looks correct - are you sure it is behaving the way you think it is? Try writing a message before your if statement to debug to see how many times it executes within the ForEach-Object loop..

Comment: Your code looks OK, I would look at reproducing your CSV file or at least putting a dummy CSV file together and testing against that.  I suspect something in your current CSV is causing the loop to halt after processing the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'extensionAttribute1' values aren't being cast as integers properly within the 'if' statement.  Try this:

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

Import-CSV C:\scripts\updateuser.csv | ForEach {
    $campus =$_.extensionAttribute1 -as [Int]
    if ($campus -lt '100'){
        Write-Host $_.sAMAccountName            
        Enable-Mailbox -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -Database NISDSRV6DB1
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand.  I cannot give the input data though since it is confidential student information.  I will test with your Write-Host suggestion and see what results I get.  Unfortunately today, I only had one secondary student in the create file so I couldn't test the actual csv. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That was it.  It didn't read the attribute as an int from the CSV.  I have updated my script and it is pulling as I'd originally expected.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try add a `;` at the end of the variable assignment

`$campus =$_.extensionAttribute1;`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the semicolon caused the script to fail.  I appreciate it though.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.  My secondary campus numbers are 1, 7, 10, 42, 43, 44, 45, and 46.  I would only recognize the less than if the number was one (strange).  If I put 0's in front of each number to 3 digits, it would recognize them.  001, 007, 010, 042, 043, 044, 045, and 046 would work and get recognized as less than 100.  Haven't found the reasoning yet, but I now need to adjust my csv export process to account for this number scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've modified my answer... you shouldn't need to adjust your export process.